# IllegalStateException in AndroidStudio from FileReader

Tags: android, android-studio, filereader, illegalstateexception

I am getting an IllegalStateException, and I'm pretty sure it's from the FileReader. I call this method on a button click:

```
public void onStartButtonTouch(View view) {

    ArrayList<String> tele = new ArrayList();

    BufferedReader reader;
    String strLine;



   try {
       FileReader wordie = new FileReader("words.txt");
       reader = new BufferedReader(wordie);

        while((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (strLine.length() == 4) {
                tele.add(strLine);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to find the file: words.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to read the file: words.txt");
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(tele.size());
    word = tele.get(index);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main_activity_play);
//when start button click, open activity play.
}
```

Here is the LogCat output:

```
Process: chinchillacongress.hangman, PID: 331
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4083)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4078)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
        at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
        at chinchillacongress.hangman.MainActivity.onStartButtonTouch(MainActivity.java:96)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4078)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

How can I fix this? I am pretty sure it's the FileReader that's causing the problem because I set breakpoints around it and it crashes at that line.

Comment: Did you realize that before that exception occurs, another one happens?
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0` It seems to me that the problem is in the parameter of the `nextInt` `Random` method

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is wrong for sure is that you are trying to get things from your `ArrayList` `tele` even when the reading fails. The following lines should be also inside the `try`, because what is the point of reading from an `ArrayList` that was not successfully filled?

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(tele.size());
word = tele.get(index);
```